# is there a way for two activities to simultaneously use the same background?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

My mainactivity and my listview activity both use the same background image and I used their respective xml files to set the background image. In the mainactivity there is a button that goes to the listview activity to pick from a set of options. Everything works fine but when you go to the listview activity, even though they use the same background, the background of the listview kinda slides up over the background of the mainactivity when going to the listview activity even though it is still the same background and I want it to just go to the listview without seeing the same background sliding over the existing background. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is Shared Element across Activity which is available in Lollipop.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions
            .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, sharedview,"sharedviewname");
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

Backward compatability is not provided so far.

**WorkAround Solution:**

1. Make the entire view of Activity1 to invisible state (expect the background view).
2. Have Activity2 with transparent background.
3. start the Activity2.

Comment: explain in your answer Activity2 to be transparent background.
I don't know how to do it, or give me useful link for it

Comment: @BasheerAL-MOMANI, there is no such link. just an idea given by me

Answer (score 0):

if you are using two **activities** then for switching use

```
Intent iSecondActivity = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
FirstActivity.this.startActivity(iSecondActivity);
FirstActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

it will remove all default activity switching effect

Answer (score 0):

Write `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION` flag when starting a new activity, it will remove transition effect of activity.

Such as, `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);`